# Running a succession of spatial analyst tools

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, fill

I am writing a very simple code in ArcMap. but it does not run correctly. I want to put a majority filter on my input raster, then use fill tool and then subtract the filled one from the last one and then reclassify the result. the problem is that when I run the code line by line, It works but when I want to run all the code together, I see a bug before "Fill" line. anybody knows what is the problem?

```
import arcpy

from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r'C:\Users\Arsalan\Documents\ArcGIS'

import arcpy.sa

from arcpy.sa import *

MajorityFilter("Meet_Raster", "EIGHT", "MAJORITY")

MajorityFilter("Meet_Raster", "EIGHT", "MAJORITY")

MajOut = MajorityFilter("Meet_Raster", "EIGHT", "MAJORITY")

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

Fill("MajOut", 12)

FillOut = Fill("MajOut", 12)

RastCalc = Raster("FillOut") - Raster("MajOut")

RastReclass = Reclassify("RastCalc", "Value", RemapRange([[0,0,"NODATA"],[1,3,1],[4,9,2],[9,15,3]]))
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 2):

I did not test, but I can see two issues:

- why do you duplicate your lines ?
- when you store a result in a variable, you should not call this variable as a text. For instance, it should be Fill(Majout, 12)

As a remark, at the end of this process, you will need a "save" to write the final output.